# image not recognised error whilst trying to add a PNG image to a tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to add images to a tkinter window, and I keep getting the error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file 'Sun.png'
```

I have tried many different ways of adding images to tkinter windows, mostly as question answers from this site and they all give the same error, the code I'm currently using is the simplest version I could find and is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file='Sun.png')
label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Im using a mac and running the code in IDLE using python3, after trying for a few hours I've run out of ideas for how this can be fixed so sorry if it's obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Your tkinter version must not support `.png` file type for images. Try your program with another file type which your tkinter supports.

Comment: ive tried png, jpg and gif and im using the newest version of tkinter

Comment: Try adding `label.photo = photo` before `label.pack()`

Comment: Check the spellings of the image and if it is top-level save a reference to it but before that restart your ide and run the script again it happened to me

Comment: no still not fixed, im using the right name and path, is it the fact that im using a mac, ive been doing some more looking around and it seems that this is a problem amoungst others using a mac

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured it out, I needed to use PIL to open the image and then assign it to a canvas, then pack the canvas to the root, the code I've ended up with is this:

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root=Tk()
root.geometry('480x360')

cond = 'Sun'

image = Image.open(str(cond) + '.png')
canvas=Canvas(root, height=200, width=200)
basewidth = 150
wpercent = (basewidth / float(image.size[0]))
hsize = int((float(image.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
image = image.resize((basewidth, hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
item4 = canvas.create_image(80, 80, image=photo)
canvas.pack(side = TOP, expand=True, fill=BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

This code achieves the needed effect of displaying a photo in a Tkinter window and also resizing that image.